# procedure error with while

Tags: mysql, while-loop

Do you know why it doesn't work?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a_loop` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `num` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_a_loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);    
    SET x = 0;
    SET str =  '';
    WHILE x < 5 DO
    SET x = x + 1;
    SET str =  CONCAT('num-', x);
    INSERT INTO a_loop (id,num) VALUES (x, str);
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

I get the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: Try putting space after the last `delimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a_loop` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `num` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The above part is not part of the stored procedure...right? Below part is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_a_loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);   
    SET x = 0;
    SET str =  '';
    WHILE x < 5 DO
    SET x = x + 1;
    SET str =  CONCAT('num-', x);
    INSERT INTO a_loop (id,num) VALUES (x, str);
    END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give a space after delimiter :)
Failed code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_a_loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);   
    SET x = 0;
    SET str =  '';
    WHILE x < 5 DO
    SET x = x + 1;
    SET str =  CONCAT('num-', x);
    INSERT INTO a_loop (id,num) VALUES (x, str);
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

After space :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_a_loop()
BEGIN
    DECLARE x  INT;
    DECLARE str  VARCHAR(255);   
    SET x = 0;
    SET str =  '';
    WHILE x < 5 DO
    SET x = x + 1;
    SET str =  CONCAT('num-', x);
    INSERT INTO a_loop (id,num) VALUES (x, str);
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```